# Encoding betfair API bot login details

Tags: python, api, security, betfair

I'm in the early stages of writing a bot for Betfair, and have got the basics of logging in, getting prices etc down, but I am concerned about security of the login I am making. In the `API-NG` [tutorial](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Non-Interactive+%28bot%29+login) (in the `Certificate Login Interface Details` section) they mention:

```
Please note:  The username and password values should be encoded when
    making the login request.
```

But what does that mean exactly, encoded how?

Currently I'm just following the tutorial Python example with:

```
payload = 'username=myusername&password=password'
headers = {'X-Application': 'SomeKey', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

resp = requests.post('https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin', data=payload,
cert=('client-2048.crt', 'client-2048.key'), headers=headers)
```

but does this mean my user and password are being sent insecurely?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK. "Encoded" refers to the payload variable's content format. You can use urllib to parse a dict into a properly formatted string. HTTPS is being used. Its safe if you keep the client-2046.key file secret in your computer